# Nginx + PHP-FPM: Connection refused on port 5000 of PHP-FPM container while port 9000 is no problem

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am training myself in Docker and I am trying to setup a Nginx + PHP FPM environment that I eventually wanna host on ECS (just for training purposes). The PHP environment has a basic Symfony 4 service running (just returns a json, nothing special). The issue however is with my Nginx container.
Something really strange happens as I have exposed the port 5000 on the PHP container in my Dockerfile for it but my Nginx container is giving me bad gateway errors when trying to access the PHP container at this port. If I change the port the Nginx container uses for the fastcgi_pass to 9000 while not changing the exposed port of the PHP container (leaving it at 5000 in Dockerfile), everything is fine and the setup just works. 
Is there anyone who could give me some hints to why this is?

I have checked `docker ps` to check for ports and indeed both port 5000 and 9000 are open on the PHP container but only port 9000 seems to be useable.

Nginx conf file

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/symfony/public;
  index index.php;

  access_log /var/log/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/error.log;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass symfony:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  }
}
```

Symfony dockerfile (shortenend)

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www/symfony
... (installation things)
COPY . /var/www/symfony
EXPOSE 5000
```

Docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  symfony:
    container_name: symfony
    build: ./symfony
    volumes:
      - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
      - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/var/logs
    networks:
      - api
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - api
    depends_on:
      - symfony
volumes:
  symfony:
networks:
  api:
    driver: "bridge"
```

Docker ps result

```
PORTS                NAMES
0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   nginx
5000/tcp, 9000/tcp   symfony
```

I expect to be able to change symfony:9000 to symfony:5000 and be able to get the result from the PHP container.

Comment: Did you update / overwrite / replace the PHP-FPM config / pools to run on port 5000 instead of 9000?

Comment: @Jonnix No I did not as I was unaware of this. After some more extensive googling I found the following: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/479
It seems that this would solve the case for changing the port.

Comment: Which is suggesting updating the config. The last comment looks like it should work?

Answer (score 0):

In official docker php image, there are `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf` ... shortly zz-docker.conf configuration file that changes `'listen="what you want"'` to `'listen=9000'`.
Therefore, you need to change (or delete) zz-docker.conf.

Related comment: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/241

Wish to solve your problem.
Thank you.